# Factory-boy / Django - Factory instance not reflecting changes to model instance

Tags: python, django, django-testing, factory-boy

I am writing tests for a website I'm working on and I'm representing the models with `factoryboy` Factory objects.

However, I've run into some behavior I found somewhat confusing and I was wondering if anyone here would be so kind to explain it to me

I'm running a test that contains the following model:

```
STATUS = (
    ('CALCULATING'),
    ('PENDING'),
    ('BUSY'),
    ('SUCCESS'),
    ('FAILED')
)


class SchoolImport(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('status'), choices=STATUS,
        max_length=50, default='CALCULATING'
    )
```

For which I've created the following factory. As you can see the `status` is set to its default value, which I found more realistic than having a randomly selected value

```
class SchoolImportFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.SchoolImport

    status = 'CALCULATING'
    school = factory.SubFactory(SchoolFactory)

    @factory.lazy_attribute
    def date(self):
        return timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
```

Below you'll see both a (simplified) version of the function that is being tested, as well as the test itself. (I've currently commented out all other code on my laptop, so the function that you see below is an accurate representation)

The gist of it is that the function receives an `id` value that it will use to fetch an `SchoolImport` object from the database and change its status. The function will be run in celery and thus returns nothing.

When I run this test through the debugger I can see that the value is changed correctly. However, when the test runs its final assertion it fails as `self.school_import.status` is still equal to `CALCULATING`.

```
#app.utils.py
def process_template_objects(school_import_pk):
    school_import = models.SchoolImport.objects.get(id=import_file_pk)
    school_import.status = 'BUSY'
    school_import.save()



#app.tests.test_utils.py
class Test_process_template_objects_function(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.school = SchoolFactory()
        self.school_import = SchoolImportFactory(
            school=self.school
        )

    def test_function_alters_school_import_status(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            self.school_import.status, 'CALCULATING'
        )
        utils.process_template_objects(self.school_import.id)
        self.assertNotEqual(
            self.school_import.status, 'CALCULATING'
        )
```

When I run this test through a debugger (with a breakpoint just before the failing assertion) and run `SchoolImport.objects.get(id=self.school_import.id).status` it does return the correct `BUSY` value.

So though the object being represented by the FactoryInstance is being updated correctly, the changes are not reflected in the factory instance itself.

Though I realize I'm probably doing something wrong here / encountering expected behavior, I was wondering how people who write tests using factoryboy fget around this behavior, or if perhaps there was a way to 'refresh' the factoryboy instance to reflect changes to the model instance.

Comment: I’m wondering if it is because you are creating a new school import object when running `models.SchoolImport.objects.get(id=import_file_pk)` what if you passed the school import object itself into the function. Something like `def process_template_objects(school_import): school_import.status = ‘BUSY’  school_import.save()`. The parameter in the get doesn’t make sense you are using `import_file_pk` but that is not defined in the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that, in `process_template_objects`, you work with a different instance of the `SchoolImport` object than the one in the test.

If you run:

```
a = models.SchoolImport.objects.get(pk=1)
b = models.SchoolImport.objects.get(pk=2)

assert a == b  # True: both refer to the same object in the database
assert a is b  # False: different Python objects, each with its own memory

a.status = 'SUCCESS'
a.save()
assert a.status == 'SUCCESS'  # True: it was indeed changed in this Python object
assert b.status == 'SUCCESS'  # False: the 'b' object hasn't seen the change
```

In order to fix this, you should refetch the instance from the database after calling `process_template_objects`:

```
utils.process_template_objects(self.school_import.id)
self.school_import.refresh_from_db()
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database for a more detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you delete a field from a model instance, accessing it again reloads the value from the database.

```
obj = MyModel.objects.first()
del obj.field
obj.field  # Loads the field from the database
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database